# How does Herbal Poultice work?

Tags: dnd-4e, alchemy

When I take the level 3 Herbal Poultice Item, how does it work? It's a potion which does the following:

> Use before you or an ally takes a short rest. The target of the herbal poultice regains an additional 2 hit points when he or she spends a healing surge at the end of the short rest.

Does the potion add extra healing to *every* healing surge the character spends during a short rest, or does it only add extra healing *once*?

Answer (score 3):

The wording is poor and unclear, unfortunately, and does not appear to have been made any clearer in any errata - the [Adventurer's Vault updates and errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/updateav.pdf) does not mention Herbal Poultice.

It does not appear to acknowledge the possibility that someone would spend *more than one* healing surge. There is no particular indication for whether the author meant you get an additional 2 hit points for each healing surge, or just an extra 2 hit points for spending any at all!

You should talk to your group about it.

Considering the *tiny* bonus of 2hp though, for a one-rest single-target potion, I would certainly allow it to apply to each healing surge.